# What is PDO scrollable cursor?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is "Fetching rows with a scrollable cursor" all about?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It creates a [cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases)) for the query, which allows you to iterate over the result set without fetching the whole result at once. A [scrollable cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases)#Scrollable_cursors), specifically, is one that allows iterating backwards.

Example use: You can scroll forward until you find the record you need and iterate back to fetch the previous records, if you need them, too.

Comment: If you're planning to use them you should also refer to the (actual) dbms documentation to find out which type of cursor you'd use. For some of them the scrollable version is far more "expensive" than a forward-only cursor, or even unavailable.

Answer (score 9):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29#Scrollable_cursors) gives this :

> With a non-scrollable cursor, also
>   known as forward-only, one can FETCH
>   each row at most once, and the cursor
>   automatically moves to the immediately
>   following row. A fetch operation after
>   the last row has been retrieved
>   positions the cursor after the last
>   row and returns SQLSTATE 02000
>   (SQLCODE +100).

And this :

> A program may position a scrollable
>   cursor anywhere in the result set
>   using the FETCH SQL statement.

You should read the article linked earlier, but this looks like some interesting information too :

> Scrollable cursors can potentially
>   access the same row in the result set
>   multiple times. Thus, data
>   modifications (insert, update, delete
>   operations) from other transactions
>   could have an impact on the result
>   set.

In PHP, you can use scrollable cursors with PDO by using prepared statements (see [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)) :

> To request a scrollable cursor for
>   your PDOStatement object, you must set
>   the PDO::ATTR_CURSOR attribute to
>   PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL when you prepare
>   the SQL statement with PDO::prepare().

(there is also an example further down that page)

What seems interesting is the ability to "scroll" through the resultset, without having to get all the data in memory to iterate over it.

Answer (score 3):

For Mysql ... not supported = not available (neither mysql(i) nor PDO):

mysqli_result::data_seek(), note that the manual states: "This function can only be used with buffered results attained from the use of the mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_query() functions." **That is, the seeking takes place on a locally cached copy of the resultset: not on the server. Thus it does not support any suggestion of a "scrollable cursor".**