# Use PDO statement multiple times when using multiple foreach loops

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have the following code:

```
if(!empty($postCountryAdd)) {
$sqlQueryLocalityAdd = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT locality_add FROM table WHERE country_add = :country_add ORDER BY locality_add ASC");
$sqlQueryLocalityAdd->execute(array(':country_add' => $postCountryAdd));

echo '<option value="">Select locality</option>';
    foreach($sqlQueryLocalityAdd as $localityAddRow) {
        //while ($localityAddRow = $sqlQueryLocalityAdd->fetch()){
        echo '<option value="';
        echo $localityAddRow["locality_add"];
        echo '">';
        echo $localityAddRow["locality_add"];
        echo '</option>';
    }
}
```

If I use   `foreach($sqlQueryLocalityAdd as $localityAddRow)` the code stops responding. Why can't I use foreach more than once? How can I fix it please?

Comment: maybe interesting? states that scrollable cursor not available in mysql. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19076778/3184785.

Comment: Your example code will not fail as it's not showing the case where you have multiple foreach blocks after each other--that's why folks are confused.  The code isn't stopping in the first iteration over the entire result set, somewehre else you trying a second full iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`$sqlQueryLocalityAdd` isn't a result set, it's a `PDOStatement` object and you can only iterate over it directly once (as noted clearly by deceze).

The `execute()` statement returns a `boolean` true or false on success of the query.

If successfully run, you need to fetch results from it post-query and iterate the array returned:

```
   $success = $sqlQueryLocalityAdd->execute(array(':country_add' => $postCountryAdd));
   if($success) {

       $results = $sqlQueryLocalityAdd->fetchAll();

       foreach($results as $localityAddRow) {
           echo '<option value="';
            ....
```

The resulting array `$results` is just a vanilla array, so you can iterate over it as many times as you want.

Note: If the `execute()` returns false, something is wrong with the query--a successful running query returning a empty result set results will still result in a `true`.

Comment: `PDOStatement` `implements Traversable`, so you *can* iterate it directly!

Comment: @deceze  indeed it does, good point.  Can't seem to find documentation of exactly how it implements it, so not sure exactly what to expect.  Does it do a fetchAll behind the scene?  Makes sense that it would be to iterate over results.

Comment: @deceze if thats true and when passed into a foreach returns the exactly same thing as `$row = $stmt->fetch()` the example code would run the same with either the foreach.  Do you know if you get an object back freom the iteration instead of an array?  I

Comment: @deceze I've never seen an example using direct iteration over the result set, so I'd like get a handle on how to do so as it seems more elegant

Comment: @deceze ah, i see the other thread of comments in another answer.  I get it now.  BTW, my answer never said you can't traverse a PDOStatement.

Comment: @Ray : returned types from the fetch: [PDOStatement::setFetchMode — Set the default fetch mode for this statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php). The `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` is useful when using 'models'?

Answer (score 0):

`$sqlQueryLocalityAdd` is an Object which **in this case - which I am showing and OP has used -** cannot be iterated through. (bold so @deceze can understand).

You can use the `fetchAll()` inside a `foreach` loop to achieve this however.

Your code should look something like this:

```
[...]
    if($sqlQueryLocalityAdd->execute(array(':country_add' => $postCountryAdd)):
        foreach($sqlQueryLocalityAdd->fetchAll() as $row):
            echo $row['column'];
            [...]
        endforeach;
    endif;
[...]
```

[Difference between an array and an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object)

Comment: You can `foreach` objects just fine, especially when they `implement Traversable`, as `PDOStatement` does.

Comment: Never seen this done, but this answers his question so... I will edit out 'only'. @deceze

Comment: You're still saying "cannot be iterated", which is clearly wrong. The OP also (cryptically) says that it works *once* (if I interpret the question correctly).

Comment: Yea, where has OP stated he used a `cursor` ? The Object OP has inside the question cannot be iterated through without changing his `Prepare` statement. So in this context, my answer is correct. @deceze

Comment: It cannot be iterated *more than once.* It *can* be iterated *once*.

Comment: I'm sure he knows how to **store** it so he can iterate as many times as he likes (creating a local variable). If you look at his commented out code however, you can see he is only trying to fetch line by line but in **two** statements which my answer does for him.. So please correct me where I am wrong? @deceze

Comment: I take objection to your ***"which in this case cannot be iterated through"***. – It ***can*** be iterated through! It just can't be iterated through *more than once.*

Comment: `in this case` - meaning the case I am showing from what OP did. I rest my case. @deceze

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result set can only be iterated once; it is then exhausted, MySQL discards it, and you cannot iterate it again.

I have never actually tried this, but to create a result set which can be iterated several times, you need a *scrollable cursor*, which you *should* be able to create thusly:

```
$sqlQueryLocalityAdd = $dbh->prepare(..., [PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL]);
```

You should then theoretically be able to iterate the result multiple times.

If that doesn't work, fetch the data into an array using `$sqlQueryLocalityAdd->fetchAll()` and iterate it as often as you want. In fact, that appears to be the only option with MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076778/476

Comment: I get it finally.  The confusing part the OP only shows a single foreach block.  It's not dying on a step of the initial full iteration over the result set generated by the statement, but it's dying because somewhere later (not shown in post) he's trying another foreach iteration.

Comment: @Ray Ding ding ding ding! We've got a winner!