# Embedded foreach loop is being executed only in first iteration of for loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to make a form being generated by using for and foreach loops. Idea is simple but for some reason i'm having odd issue. For loop is supposed to have 5 iterations and this is working fine but in this for loop i have embedded a foreach loop. Foreach loop seems to be done only on first iteration of for loop. I think code is ok but maybe multiple concatenations obscure my vision to find where my mistake is. This is how the code looks at the moment:

```
<?php
include("pdo.php");

$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM Ingredients');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
                echo "<label>Ingredient $i</label><select name='ingredient $i'>";
                foreach ($stmt as $row) {
                    echo ('<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>' . "\n");
                }
                echo "</select><br>";
            }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In other words only first list is being populated but next four lists are empty.

Comment: $stmt runs out at the end of its first loop. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36428542/2960971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have read all rows returned in the statement you can't read them again, you would need to rewind the result before populating each select. Instead use [fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get result as an array.

Comment: Thank you for hint. I added fetchall() and now everything works as intended.